# Does saving the super instance as a variable of the class is considered good practice?

Tags: python

Let's I have the class `Dog` which inherits from `Animal`, is it considered good practice to do the following:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__parentcls__ = super(Dog, self)
```

or should I just do `super(Dog, self)` every time I need to access my parent class?

Comment: Not sure why would one need that. Because for example `super().method()` in any method, will call the `super` classes that `method`

Comment: @hansolo Basically it's just to make my code a bit more readable

Comment: I don't see how you're achieving that, because you're doing something unconventional. I know what `super` does, but if I see `self.__parentcls__` I now have to try to figure out what's assigned to that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it, so you're saying to just stick with `super(Dog, self)` when I need the parent class?

Comment: Just call init method of the parent class and you will have all the properties of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments already indicate, there's no reason here to go against conventions.  Using `super` directly is already readable for python developers.

You should note that in python3, you use `super()`, not `super(Dog, self)`, which naturally makes it more readable.

Also, one more disadvantage in your approach is that it creates a reference cycle (self references the super object, which references self, or: `self.__parentcls__.__self__ is self`).  While this isn't necessarilly a problem (python handles reference cycles well), it may impose some overhead (e.g. object will not get destroyed as soon as possible, only when gc cycles run).

EDIT: @Mehul aptly points out another real drawback of your approach: basically, it isn't subclass friendly.

Answer (score -1):

When we create a variable in both parent and child classes with the same name and try to access it using a parent's class reference, which is holding a child class's object, then what do we get?

In order to understand this, let us consider the example below where we declare a variable x with the same name in both Parent and Child classes.

`class Parent { // Declaring instance variable by name` x`String x = "Parent's Instance Variable"; public void print() { System.out.println(x); } } class Child extends Parent { // Hiding Parent class's variable`x `by defining a variable in child class with same name. String x = "Child's Instance Variable"; @Override public void print() { System.out.print(x); // If we still want to access variable from super class, we do that by using 'super.x' System.out.print(", " + super.x + "\n"); } }`

And now, if we try to access x using below code, System.out.println(parent.x) will print:

`Parent parent = new Child(); System.out.println(parent.x) // Output -- Parent's Instance Variable`

Well generally, we say that the Child class will override the variable declared in the Parent class, and parent.x will give us whatever the Child's object is holding. Because it is the same thing, it happens while we do the same kind of operation on methods.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but your answer is in Java which is not the same as my question which is in python

Comment: You're making a good point, but it would be better to include a python example